# Unable to serialize custom object activeandroid

Tags: sqlite, serialization, activeandroid

I am trying to store some custom object as a blob in SqlLite db. The object is a field of a class extending Model. All other fields (of primitive types) go successfully in the DB, but the custom one - it is null always.

```
@Table(name = "data")
public class Data extends Model {

@Column(name = "number")
private int number;

@Column(name = "blob")
private Contact blob;

...
```

This is how i store the entity

```
Data data = new Data(0, new Contact(id, name, number));
data.save();
```

Here is the contact class

```
public class Contact {
private String id;
private String name;
private String number;

...
```

I believe a TypeSerializer is needed, so I've created one.

```
public class ContactSerializer extends TypeSerializer {

private static final String ELEMENTS_DELIMITER = ";";

@Override
public Object deserialize(Object asString) {
    String[] afterSplit = ((String) asString).split(ELEMENTS_DELIMITER);
    return new Contact(afterSplit[0], afterSplit[1], afterSplit[2]);
}

@Override
public Class<?> getDeserializedType() {
    return Contact.class;
}

@Override
public SerializedType getSerializedType() {
    return SerializedType.STRING;
}

@Override
public Object serialize(Object asContact) {
    Contact temp = (Contact) asContact;
    return temp.getId() + ELEMENTS_DELIMITER + temp.getName() + ELEMENTS_DELIMITER
            + temp.getNumber();
}
```

}

When i query the db I got object with this particular field "Contact" as null always. Where might be the problem? Do I need to specify which is the TypeSerializer for my object? Or the implementation of TypeSerializer I've created is wrong?

Comment: Hey there, you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 2):

You also need to extent Contact from Model:

```
@Table(name = "contact")
public class Contact extends Model{
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "number")
    private String number;
}
```

Now everything should work out of the box. It's a bit late for a response but perhaps I will help someone else.